# Does every time COM COMPONENTS, constructor string update require in VB? when COM component is deployed in windows server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, com, dcom

Does every time COM COMPONENTS, constructor string update require in VB? when COM component is deployed in windows server.

We have already configured all components on server, however when we add new changes then after deployment it does not works. So we do manually update constructor string and after this it works. Looking for best automated recommended way to do this process?

STEPS:
Run below command to open COM components registration window:
Dcomcnfg

Then expand My Computer-->COM+ Applications-->Your Application-->Components-->your COM components-->Right Click-->Properties-->

After this Properties Window will open:

Activation tab-->Enable object construction--> Constructor String--> Here changes require on each time manually, so looking for this solution?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Not clear what your question really is. Only will say that interfaces are supposed to be immutable. So, once you change an interface, then you're supposed to provide a new CLSID, etc. Can you cheat a little? The "correct" answer is no. The not so correct answer rooted in a little experience is "maybe a little."

Comment: added more steps for you information -Joseph Willcoxson

Comment: If the component is in use, you must restart either the process(es) holding it (Library application case) or shutdown the COM+ application (Server application case).

Comment: Thank you for your response, we follow these steps manually: 1. Disable components 2. Update construction string  3. Update transaction 4. Start com components.  However, we do not want to perform these steps manually on each deployment, do we have any other options or this steps must require to perform manually?